# Getting common day from nested javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of Objects and I am trying to map out the most common date.

```
{data: [
  { 
    name: "Mark".
    days: [ "2017-04-27", "2017-04-17"]
  }, 
  {
    name: "Dave".
    days: [ "2017-04-27", "2017-04-13"]

   },
   {
    name: "Sarah".
    days: [ "2017-04-09", "2017-04-27"]
   }
]}
```

I am trying to iterate them using a forEach and then iterating over each `days` array but that feels like a bad solution with bad time complexity.

Comment: Please show what the expected outcome is and show the code you have tried as well

Comment: @Phil - He had posted full code, and it was running. Somebody, badly edited it down and ruined it.

Comment: @Deadpool there are no edits on this post 

Comment: [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is a textual format, what you have there is a javascript object. They are not the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: Finding commonality in object days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64021155/js-finding-commonality-in-object-days)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. This is the confusion here @Deadpool

Comment: for fear of going on a bit, please don't artificially add tags (`JS:`) into your question titles. Have a read of [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 0):

Start by collecting days and counts into a `Map`.

You can then convert that `Map` to an array, sort by the counts (descending) then pick the first entry to get the most frequent day.

```js
// The object from your question
const obj = {"data":[{"name":"Mark","days":["2017-04-27","2017-04-17"]},{"name":"Dave","days":["2017-04-27","2017-04-13"]},{"name":"Sarah","days":["2017-04-09","2017-04-27"]}]}

// Collect days and counts into a Map
const dayCount = obj.data.flatMap(({ days }) => days).reduce((map, day) =>
  map.set(day, (map.get(day) ?? 0) + 1), new Map())

// Convert the Map to an array and sort it
const sortedMap = Array.from(dayCount, ([ day, count ]) => ({ day, count }))
  .sort(({ count: countA }, { count: countB }) => countB - countA)
  
const mostFrequentDay = sortedMap[0]?.day

console.info("mostFrequentDay:", mostFrequentDay)
console.log("sortedMap:", sortedMap)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nested forEach loop to traverse days and track the `count` and `date`

```js
const sample = {
  data: [
    {
      name: "Mark",
      days: ["2017-04-27", "2017-04-17"],
    },
    {
      name: "Dave",
      days: ["2017-04-27", "2017-04-13"],
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      days: ["2017-04-09", "2017-04-27"],
    },
  ],
};

const mostFrequentDay = (arr) => {
  let date = "";
  let count = 0;
  const all = {};

  arr.forEach(({ days }) =>
    days.forEach((day) => {
      all[day] = (all[day] ?? 0) + 1;
      if (all[day] > count) {
        date = day;
        count = all[day];
      }
    })
  );
  return date;
};

console.log("Most Frequent Day: ", mostFrequentDay(sample.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked a lot to get your answer. Also, you `did not take care what if more than 1 date has same frequency of occurrence`. I took care of that too. Hope, this helps!

```js
const sample = {
  data: [
    {
      name: "Mark",
      days: ["2017-04-27", "2017-04-17"],
    },
    {
      name: "Dave",
      days: ["2017-04-27", "2017-04-13"],
    },
    {
      name: "Sarah",
      days: ["2017-04-09", "2017-04-27"],
    },
  ],
};

const mostFrequentDay = arr => {
  let dateArray = [];
  let freqDate = [];
  let maxCount = 0;
  let count = 0;
  arr.map(item => dateArray.push(...item.days));
  dateArray.map(item => {
    let myItem = item;
    dateArray.map(()=> item === myItem? count++: null);
    if(count > maxCount){freqDate = [];freqDate.push(myItem);}
    else if (count = maxCount){freqDate.push(myItem);}
  });
  return freqDate;
};

console.log("Most Frequent Day: ", mostFrequentDay(sample.data));
```