# Finding commonality in object days

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects where I want to find out what consecutive days are the most common between all of them and then choose the first day of that consecutive day pair.

```
let data = [
   {
     name: "mike",
     city: "Los Angeles",
     days: ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-03","2020-01-18", "2020-01-19"]
   },

   {
     name: "Kenny",
     city: "Chicago",
     days: ["2020-04-02", "2020-04-12","2020-04-19"]

   },
 
   {
     name: "James",
     city: "Los Angeles",
     days: ["2020-05-02", "2020-05-12","2020-05-19"]
   },
    {
     name: "Maggie",
     city: "Los Angeles",
     days: ["2020-11-12", "2020-11-13","2020-05-19"]
   },
   {
     name: "Ricardo",
     city: "Los Angeles",
     days: ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-03","2020-05-19"]
   },
   {
     name: "Reeny",
     city: "Chicago",
     days: ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-04","2020-05-09"]
   },

];
```

so for example, for Los Angeles, I'd want to return:

```
{
   city: "Los Angeles", 
   day: "2020-01-02",
   people: ["mike", "ricardo"],
}
```

"Maggie" wouldn't be in since her available consecutive days appear less than Mike and James.

For Mike and James,  `"2020-01-02"` and `"2020-01-03"` appears most for Los Angeles.
For Chicago, I'd want to return just an empty string since I don't have any consecutive days.

So far, I iterated through the data and pushed the city to an object.  If the city is already in the object, I push each `day` to the existing array.  If the `city` is not in the hash object, then I just set it and have it equal the `days`

```
let obj = {};
data.forEach(x => {
   if (map[x.city]) {
       x.days.forEach(y => {
          map[x.city].push(y);
       })
   } else {
      map[x.city] = x.days;
   }
});

for (x in obj) {
    let arr = [...new Set(obj[x])]
    obj[x] = arr.sort();
}
```

my result is an object with the city as a key and the value is the days (with the duplicates removed via Set) :

```
obj = {
    "Los Angeles": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-03","2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-12","2020-05-19", "2020-11-12", "2020-11-13"],
    "Chicago": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-04","2020-04-02", "2020-04-12","2020-04-19", "2020-05-09"]
    }
```

From this point, I'm not sure what to do. I imagine it's possible to accomplish this but I don't know the next step here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alasql
https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Examples

with alasql can you make: DISTINCT or GROUP etc.

example:

```
// Fill table with data
var person = [ 
    { name: 'bill' , sex:'M', income:50000 },
    { name: 'sara' , sex:'F', income:100000 },
    { name: 'larry' , sex:'M', income:90000 },
    { name: 'olga' , sex:'F', income:85000 },
];

// Do the query
var res = alasql("SELECT * FROM ? person WHERE sex='F' AND income > 60000", [person]);

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res);
```